# Using a global boolean variable for logger "on/off"?

Tags: rust

I develop a mobile and desktop app which has a checkbox "enable/disable debug logger". A logger will write data into a file.

Since none of the Rust loggers I know of are capable of switching its on/off state **dynamically**, I've decided to use a global boolean variable for it and wrap every `log::info/debug/error` into a condition of whether or not the variable is true.

A user will check/uncheck a checkbox, and the `IS_LOGGER_ENABLED` will change its value accordingly.

Then, in each place I want to debug, I'll use this statement:

```
//..........
if IS_LOGGER_ENABLED { //check the state each time
  log::debug!("test123")
}
```

Are there caveats?

Is there a better way, or more canonical one?

Comment: `log` has the functionality for you to provide your own log handler. You just need to write your own handler and it should work without any issues. https://docs.rs/log/0.4.14/log/fn.set_logger.html

Comment: @Locke how will that address anything in my question?

Answer (score 3):

For the general case your solution should be fine, but there is one small caviat. Your project may not be the only one using the log crate. Some of your dependencies may also use it. Most of the time you need to explicitly enable a features to enable logging, but there might be some edge cases.

Here is an example of how you can implement a custom logger using the [`Log`](https://docs.rs/log/0.4.14/log/trait.Log.html) trait and link it so it gets used whenever one of the log macros is called. This way you won't need to wrap every log macro and it should also cover the edge case of a dependency logging messages when it should be disabled.

```rust
pub struct ToggledLogger<L> {
    toggle: Arc<AtomicBool>,
    inner_logger: L,
}

impl<L: Log> Log for ToggledLogger<L> {
    // Usually this gets used to check if a logger accepts a certain message level, but 
    // we can add the enable check here. It calls this before sending each log message
    // to avoid the overhead of formatting a log messages that might get discarded.
    fn enabled(&self, metadata: &Metadata<'_>) -> bool {
        self.inner_logger.enabled(metadata) && self.toggle.load(Ordering::SeqCst)
    }

    fn log(&self, record: &Record<'_>) {
        self.inner_logger.log(record);
    }

    fn flush(&self) {
        self.inner_logger.flush();
    }
}


// This Arc<AtomicBool> is used in place of a global variable to toggle logging.
let toggle = Arc::new(AtomicBool::new(true));

let custom_logger = ToggledLogger {
    toggle: toggle.clone(),
    // Just use a log handler from any of a number of supported crates or write your own 
    inner_logger: Foo,
};

// Tell the log crate to direct all log messages through the custom logger
log::set_boxed_logger(Box::new(custom_logger));

// Enable/disable later using the Arc<AtomicBool> we passed to the logger.
toggle.store(should_logging_be_enabled, Ordering::SeqCst);
```

Comment: And how would the user then switch it on or off, **at runtime**? And it could be multiple times on and off

Comment: @Rurik21Ami You can use `toggle.store(true, Ordering::SeqCst)` to turn it on and `toggle.store(false, Ordering::SeqCst)` to turn it off. There is no limit on the number of times it is used. You can also clone `toggle` as many times as you want and they will still refer to the same `AtomicBool`. `toggle` and any of its clones can also be sent to other threads without issues.

Comment: but why so complex solution? how is it better than a simple global boolean variable?

Comment: The main benefit is that you can set it up once then forget about it. This helps you keep your code less cluttered and more verbose. It also future-proofs your enable/disable logging option. For example you may want to enable logging on a dependency (Ex: If you decide to put in ads, the ad manager will probably have options for logging that you might want to enable). Plus it honestly isn't very complex. It just comes down to implementing a trait to wrap another logger then telling the `log` crate to use to the new trait.

Comment: The arguments "set up once and forget", "it's not too much complex" -- aren't valid. How is it better, if it is at all, than a simple boolean variable?

Comment: `It also future-proofs your enable/disable logging option. For example you may want to enable logging on a dependency` --> how does it future-proof them? how is that superiour to a global boolean variable?

Comment: Global boolean values are generally a bad idea for code organization. A large number of codestyles and code manuals disapprove of them because they encourage spaghetti code. Simply put, if you can avoid a global variable, do so. Additionally, @Locke said in his post: "Your project may not be the only one using the log crate. Some of your dependencies may also use it. Most of the time you need to explicitly enable a features to enable logging, but there might be some edge cases." If you want your dependency to also log/not log based on your boolean, they won't refer to your global variable.

Comment: @OptimisticPeach: But `log::set_boxed_logger` is actually setting a global variable, so you can replace the `Arc<AtomicBool>` with a global static `AtomicBool` and the code will be exactly equivalent. Not likely that you will be using two `ToggledLogger` at the same time.

Comment: `The main benefit is that you can set it up once then forget about it` --> that's not an argument. There's no need to set up anything with a simple global variable in the first place.

Comment: `Additionally, @Locke said in his post: "Your project may not be the only one using the log crate. Some of your dependencies may also use it.` --> who knows better whether or not that's the case: me or him?

Comment: @Rurik21Ami Look, if you're going to argue this strongly on the advice given to you in good faith, perhaps it would be most productive that you go out and try not using it for yourself... this advice was not meant with bad intentions, so being this rude about it and defending what is regarded as _bad code practice_ is simply unproductive.

Comment: @rodrigo While it is indeed unlikely that you want to have two `ToggledLogger`, it is possible that you might want to give access to the `AtomicBool` to places other than the module in which the static is defined, perhaps even other crates. Hence, designing it once, _correctly_ with great flexibility, with little cost (since most likely you will not be toggling logging 1000s of times per second, on multiple threads), is most definitely the best way to go about it.